# Different meanings of [Required] in foreign property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

What's the differnce of using Required on Id field,

```
[Required]
public int? UserId {get; set;}

[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public User User {get; set;}
```

on the Navigation Property or

```
public int? UserId {get; set;}

[Required]
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public User User {get; set;}
```

in both:

```
[Required]
public int? UserId {get; set;}

[Required]
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public User User {get; set;}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core? Those are different technologies. But, in this case, none of them make difference since Conventions establish that "int" (a non-nullable type) cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

here, just read it and it'll help you :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields